# What Fungus is this? Is this a good or a bad fungus?

Tags: identification, houseplants, fungus

I found this web-resembling white colored fungus(or spider webs? highly unlikely) on the soil in one of my houseplant(Devil's Ivy). I have no idea about this or any other fungus. Here are the pics:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't know what kind it is, but that is some fantastic mycelium action!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a picture of the fruiting body, "the mushroom", it's hard to provide a positive ID. There is a great chance, however, that this is simply a case of the very common "flowerpot mushroom", known to mycologists and fungi fans alike as [Leucocoprinus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leucocoprinus), the most common species being [L. birnbaumii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leucocoprinus_birnbaumii).

More info: http://www.mushroomexpert.com/leucocoprinus_birnbaumii.html

[image]

[image]